# `respond_to?` vs. `respond_to_missing?`

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

What is the point of defining `respond_to_missing?` as opposed to defining `respond_to?`? What goes wrong if you redefine `respond_to?` for some class?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Without [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F) defined, trying to get the method via [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) will fail:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing name, *args
    p args
  end

  def respond_to? name, include_private = false
    true
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar  #=> []
f.respond_to? :bar  #=> true
f.method :bar  # NameError: undefined method `bar' for class `Foo'

class Foo
  def respond_to? *args; super; end  # “Reverting” previous redefinition

  def respond_to_missing? *args
    true
  end
end

f.method :bar  #=> #<Method: Foo#bar>
```

[Marc-André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune) (a Ruby core committer) has a good [blog post on `respond_to_missing?`](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html).

Comment: Out of interest, what good is `respond_to?` for then. Is there a legitimate use case for it?

Comment: @BrendonMuir For redefining it? Never, really. But `respond_to?` should always be the method that’s called. You should not be calling `respond_to_missing?` directly.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant :) Good to know :)

Comment: In my opinion `respond_to_missing?` should never return true as default. Instead, it should be something like `check_if_method_meet_condition || super` . Another thing is that it is usually defined as  `respond_to_missing(method_name, include_private = false)`

Comment: @PiotrGalas If `method_missing` exists (and never raises NameError itself), then `respond_to_missing?` returning `true` always makes perfect sense. But this is just a contrived example. As for the latter point: I was lazy, and the arguments are never used here.

Answer (score 5):

It's a good practice to create **respond_to_missing?** if you are overriding **method_missing**. That way, the class will tell you the method you are calling exists, even though it's not explicitly declared.

respond_to? should probably not be overriden :)