# Ruby - actually get ALL methods for an instance

Tags: ruby

In this question:

[How to list all methods for an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby)

You can call `foo.methods` and get all methods. But this does not get all methods. Example in Rails, with ActiveStorage:

```
Image.first.specimens.first.methods.include?(:variant)
# => false
Image.first.specimens.first.respond_to?(:variant)
# => true
Image.first.specimens.first.variant
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
Image.first.specimens.first.method(:variant)
# => #<Method: ActiveStorage::Attachment(id: integer, name: string, record_type: string, record_id: integer, blob_id: integer, created_at: datetime)#variant>
```

Given that an ArgumentError is being raised, it `respond_to?`s, and I can grab the method, it ***does*** have the variant method. But it is not shown with `.methods`. How can I see a full list of methods?

Comment: _"Given that [....] it does have the variant method"_ – your conclusion is wrong. Messages and methods are closely related, but independent of each other in general. An object can respond to a message without implementing a method with the same name. An object can also implement a certain method without responding to the corresponding message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all methods for an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you missed the last paragraph in the accepted answer of linked post [How to list all methods for an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595184/how-to-list-all-methods-for-an-object-in-ruby):

> **Added** Note that :has_many does not add methods directly. Instead, the ActiveRecord machinery uses the Ruby method_missing and responds_to techniques to handle method calls on the fly. As a result, the methods are not listed in the methods method result.

To make it clearer what happens a code example:

```
class Foo
  def hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    case name
      when :unknown_method
        puts "handle unknown method %s" % name # name is a symbol
      else
        super #raises NoMethodError unless there is something else defined
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
p foo.respond_to?(:hello) #-> true
p foo.respond_to?(:unknown_method) #-> false
foo.unknown_method  #-> 'handle unknown method unknown_method'
foo.another_unknown_method  #-> Exception
```

The method `unknown_method` is never defined, but there is a method to handle unknown methods. So the class makes the impression of an existing method, but there is none.

Maybe [How can I get source code of a method dynamically and also which file is this method locate in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-method-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-me) helps the get information about the content:

```
Foo.instance_method(:method_missing).source_location
```

### Addition

When you define your own `method_missing`, then you should also change the behaviour of `respond_to?` with `respond_to_missing?`

```
  def respond_to_missing?(method, *)
    return method == :unknown_method || super
    #or if you have a list of methods:
    #~ return %i{unknown_method}.include?(method) || super
    #or with a regex for 
    #~ method =~ /another_(\w+)/ || super
  end
end
```

See also [`respond_to?` vs. `respond_to_missing?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793060/respond-to-vs-respond-to-missing) for details.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you expose fake methods via `method_missing`, you should mirror the changes in `respond_to_missing?`

Comment: And instead of raising your own `NoMethodError`, you should just call `super`.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the hint. I adapted my answer

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I extende my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Good answer. There's no need for "Addition". Just edit as though you were responding to comments made on a draft of an article or book.